# How can I tell what version of Java I have installed?

Tags: java, openjdk, jdk

I want to start toying around with java (eventually getting to the point where I can write basic little programs for android or web), but I've managed to have java messed up on my computer (from past experiments).

I'm not sure which version of java I have, and would like to know if there is a command to see the version of java that is installed and active. Also, which version works best? All this on 32bit Ubuntu 12.04

EDIT:
Ok, so it seems like I have both openjdk 6 and 7, with openjdk 7 in use. I want to use openjdk 7, so how do I uninstall openjdk 6? Is just via USC good enough or is there a command that should be run?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This command should tell you what is currently providing the Java virtual machine (`java`) and the Java compiler (`javac`):

```
file /etc/alternatives/java /etc/alternatives/javac
```

This assumes the "alternatives" system is working properly, which might not be the case, depending on how Java has been "messed up" in the past. To check this, run:

```
file `which java javac`
```

If the alternatives system is working correctly and being used by Java, then you should see:

```
/usr/bin/java:  symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/java'
/usr/bin/javac: symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/javac'
```

Otherwise please **edit your question** to provide details. Then it should be possible to give a more specific answer.

---

You can remove `openjdk-6` with the Software Center. There are multiple packages associated with it, so you may need to remove more than one packages. (All the `openjdk-6 packages are [listed here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6).)

Or you can use the command-line:

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-6-\* icedtea-6-\*
```

However, whichever method you use, you may want to check first to see what depends on these packages--you might have software installed that specifically needs version 6. (Probably not, but possibly.)

You can check for this by *simulating* the removal operation on the command-line:

```
apt-get -s remove openjdk-6-\* icedtea-6-\*
```

This will show you the effects of removing those packages, including what other packages would be removed as well. (You'll notice that since this is a simulation, you don't need `sudo`.)

If you want to be able to continue using [Java content online in your web browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet) (this is not the same thing as [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript)), then before you remove any `icedtea-6-` or `openjdk-6-` packages (except perhaps `openjdk-6-jdk`), you should make sure you have `icedtea-7-` packages installed corresponding to whatever `icedtea-6-` packages are installed.

Answer (score 117):

The simplest way is:

`update-java-alternatives -l` shows you all the Java versions you have installed.

`java -version` shows you the Java version you are using.

`java -showversion` shows you the Java version you are using and help.

Normally it would be OpenJDK.

Answer (score 18):

[image: Java]

```
java -version
javac -version
```

These commands display what version of `java` (the interpreter that runs Java programs) and `javac` (the compiler that creates them) you have installed.

See the image above for details.

Answer (score 3):

This what I did that worked for me :

Open your terminal :

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Then type ( or copy and paste from here ) these commands one at a time:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java7-installer*
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer*
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*java*
sudo apt-get update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Then to be on the safe side, I would reboot.

To find your java version type

```
java -version
```

and you should see output similar to this:

```
java version "1.7.0_04"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-b20)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0-b21, mixed mode)
```

Although yours will be in 32 bits.

I highly suggest using Java 7, but the updates will try to install Java 6 too. That is OK. But your default should still come up as 7. Everything I have thrown at it works as long as your video card drivers work.

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Comment: How do install java 8 ?