# Gradle JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory

Tags: java, gradle

I have tried and looked at the past Gradle Java_HOME questions, however none of the options seems to work.
I followed [this website](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-gradle-on-ubuntu-20-04/) to install Gradle. However, all the Gradle commands I run result in the following error:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation.
```

I'm also using OpenJDK 11 and

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241
```

Comment: you can try the command: `which java` to find where is your java installation

Comment: jdk1.8.0_241 is a java 8, and not a java 11

Comment: use `update-java-alternatives -l` https://askubuntu.com/a/150065/734218

Comment: the error is saying your `$JAVA_HOME` is pointing to the wrong location, probably this directory `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241` doesn't exists

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find java home by using the following command:

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 > /dev/null | grep 'java.home'
```

It will print something like:

```
java.home = /path/to/java_home
```

You can set the output of this command as JAVA_HOME by copying the path and adding the following line to your `~/.bashrc`.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java_home
```